# Getting rid of Duplicate values - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below 5 tables -

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSP_EpmProject](
    [ProjectUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectAuthorName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MSP_EpmProject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ProjectUID] ASC)) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project_CI_Mapping](
    [ProjectName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [CI] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ca_owned_resource]( 
    [resource_name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [resource_description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [resource_family] [int] NULL,
    [resource_class] [int] NOT NULL,
    [resource_status] [int] NULL,   
    [resource_tag] [nvarchar](64) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimTeamProject](
    [ProjectNodeSK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectNodeGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectNodeName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ProjectNodeSK] ASC))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimIteration](
    [IterationSK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IterationName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [IterationGUID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([IterationSK] ASC))
```

I have a simple query that tries to get columns from all the tables, but it is returning me duplicate values. Trying INNER JOIN returns me duplicate values & when trying LEFT OUTER JOIN it gives me NULL values for "DimIteration.IterationName".

The query is -

```
select m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName "Project Manager", p.CI,c.resource_tag "Alt CI ID", i.IterationName 
from MSP_EpmProject m, Project_CI_Mapping p, ca_owned_resource c, DimTeamProject t, DimIteration i
where i.ProjectGUID = UPPER(CAST(t.ProjectNodeGUID AS NVARCHAR(256)))
and p.CI = c.resource_name
and m.ProjectName = p.ProjectName
order by m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName, p.CI,c.resource_tag, i.IterationName
```

Possible Mappings are -

```
MSP_EpmProject.ProjectName =  Project_CI_Mapping.ProjectName 
Project_CI_Mapping.CI = ca_owned_resource.resource_name
ca_owned_resource.resource_tag = DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeName
DimIteration.ProjectGUID = UPPER(CAST(DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeGUID AS NVARCHAR(256)))
```

What would be a suitable solution for the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the reason most database tables have IDs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `CROSS JOIN` in your query. If you rewrite it using the newer ANSI-92 syntax (which i would recommend doing anyway, for [reasons explained here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)) you can see where the cross join lies:

```
select  m.ProjectName,
        m.ProjectAuthorName "Project Manager", 
        p.CI,c.resource_tag "Alt CI ID", 
        i.IterationName 
from    MSP_EpmProject m
        INNER JOIN Project_CI_Mapping p
            ON m.ProjectName = p.ProjectName
        INNER JOIN ca_owned_resource c
            ON p.CI = c.resource_name
        CROSS JOIN DimTeamProject t
        INNER JOIN DimIteration i
            ON i.ProjectGUID = UPPER(CAST(t.ProjectNodeGUID AS NVARCHAR(256)))
order by m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName, p.CI,c.resource_tag, i.IterationName;
```

Basically there is nothing to relate `DimTeamProject` to any of the tables before hand. Based on the fact that you have this

```
ca_owned_resource.resource_tag = DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeName
```

as a possible relation, and it doesn't feature in your query at all I would suggest your query needs to be:

```
select m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName "Project Manager", p.CI,c.resource_tag "Alt CI ID", i.IterationName 
from MSP_EpmProject m, Project_CI_Mapping p, ca_owned_resource c, DimTeamProject t, DimIteration i
where i.ProjectGUID = UPPER(CAST(t.ProjectNodeGUID AS NVARCHAR(256)))
and p.CI = c.resource_name
and m.ProjectName = p.ProjectName
and c.resource_tag = t.ProjectNodeName -- NEW Clause
order by m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName, p.CI,c.resource_tag, i.IterationName
```

However, as I've already said, I'd recommend ANSI 92 explicit joins so your query would become:

```
SELECT  m.ProjectName,
        m.ProjectAuthorName "Project Manager", 
        p.CI,c.resource_tag "Alt CI ID", 
        i.IterationName 
FROM    MSP_EpmProject m
        INNER JOIN Project_CI_Mapping p
            ON m.ProjectName = p.ProjectName
        INNER JOIN ca_owned_resource c
            ON p.CI = c.resource_name
        INNER JOIN DimTeamProject t
            ON t.ProjectNodeName = c.resource_tag
        INNER JOIN DimIteration i
            ON i.ProjectGUID = UPPER(CAST(t.ProjectNodeGUID AS NVARCHAR(256)))
ORDER BY m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName, p.CI,c.resource_tag, i.IterationName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without studying the question in too much detail, one way to get rid of duplicates is to insert a [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause before the `ORDER BY`, like this:

```
select m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName "Project Manager", p.CI,c.resource_tag "Alt CI ID", i.IterationName 
from MSP_EpmProject m, Project_CI_Mapping p, ca_owned_resource c, DimTeamProject t, DimIteration i
where i.ProjectGUID = UPPER(CAST(t.ProjectNodeGUID AS NVARCHAR(256)))
and p.CI = c.resource_name
and m.ProjectName = p.ProjectName
GROUP BY m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName, p.CI,c.resource_tag, i.IterationName
order by m.ProjectName,m.ProjectAuthorName, p.CI,c.resource_tag, i.IterationName
```

Another way is to insert `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` and before the first column you wish to return.

e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT m.ProjectName...`